# Show an image for few seconds by clicking on another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I have an image that is a link, how can I make sure that appear when someone clicking before another image for few seconds and then go to the link shown?

Comment: What have you tried? At least post some HTML or some pseudo code of what you're trying to do .

Comment: @adeneo I just want some tips on how to make it

Comment: Your question is far from clear! At least to me... The best thing would be some sort of code you have tried, or at least try to explain it a little better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following logic:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ex6kT/)

```
$('a').one('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).delay(1000).queue(this.click).find('img')[0].src = "newImageURL";   
});
```